# When declar multiple javascript objects with more than one levels, what is the most elegant way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently instantiate objects like this:

```
$scope.vppInfo.contract={};
$scope.vppInfo.contract.companyInfo={};
            $scope.vppInfo.contract.companyInfo.custNumber=contract.custNumber;
            $scope.vppInfo.contract.companyInfo.company=contract.TekOpenAccountClient.company;
            $scope.vppInfo.contract.contract_type=contract.VPPContractType.id;
            $scope.vppInfo.contract.action=action;
            $scope.vppInfo.contract.created_at= contract.created_at;
```

Its getting really ugly. But seems there is no other way I know to improve it...

What is the best way to declare objects in this senario that will declare objects in more than one layer (level) attached to one object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered:

```
$scope.vppInfo.contract = {
    companyInfo: {
        custNumber: contract.custNumber,
        company: contract.TekOpenAccountClient.company
    },
    contract_type: contract.VPPContractType.id,
    action: action,
    created_at: contract.created_at
};
```

Comment: You were 30 seconds faster with your answer ;)

Comment: I prefer this than the dot notation